# Appending a value from a Column to another Column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the type of my data:

[image]

I wish to write a Python script that can help me do the following:

If ABC company bought chocolate and tea, then I want to both of the products they bought, and append it into another column like the following output:

[image]

I have been trying to do it using Pandas but can't iterate through the columns/rows like I would want to.
Any and All ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as  text, we can not copy data from image

Answer (score 1):

Let us try with `transform`

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.groupby('Company').Product.transform(lambda x : ';'.join(set(x)))
```